# Runtime check failure #2 when using char data type instead of int

Tags: c

I've written a simple code in C that takes in an ASCII decimal value and returns the char value that corresponds to the inputted decimal. For example, 65 would print out 'A'.

```
int x;
printf("Enter an ASCII number: ");
scanf_s("%d", &x);
printf("Entered letter is: %c\n", x);
```

However if I change line 1 from `int x` to `char x`, the program will run into run-time check failure #2 stating stack around variable x was corrupted when I test the program with x = 65. I understand this usually happens if I am out of bounds of assigned memory, but 65 should still be within the memory limit of char. Why is this happening?

Comment: You explicitly ask `scanf_s` to read an `int` value, and store it in an `int` variable. Why do you think you could store that four-byte (usually) `int` value in a single-byte (usually) `char`? If you want to read a single byte and store in a single byte, use `%hhd` instead (if it's supported by MSVC).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So it wasn't the data type declaration that's the issue but the scanf line?

Comment: But you will store a probably 4 byte value in a variable that should take only one byte.

Comment: @anastaciu Thank you for your comment, I have understood what's wrong with the code now. So just final clarification to make sure I have got this fully understood: even if I'm reading into a char data type, if I specified the input to be int, then it will read the input with size of int?

Comment: The `scanf` format specifier and the corresponding argument must be matching. A mismatch in types result in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @cryolock yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `scanf_s("%d", &x);`, you tell c to scan for a decimal integer (`%d`) of type `int`, and store it in a `char`. Because an `int` is 4 bytes, and a `char` 1 byte, you are writing outside the char, corrupting the surrounding memory.